# ObservableCollection Collection Changed event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observable collection in my ViewModel, bound to a datagrid.  I want to implement some logic for refreshing the data in other windows based on changes to the collection/ updates to the database (using LINQ to SQL).

Here is my view model code:

```
    public FTViewModel(int JobID)
    {
        _windowCloseAction = new DelegateCommand(OnWindowClose);
        _oFTrn = new ObservableFilesTransmitted(_dataDc, JobID);
        _oFTrn.CollectionChanged += oFTrnCollectionChanged;
    }

    void oFTrnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (FilesTransmitted f in e.NewItems)
                f.PropertyChanged += FilesTransmitted_PropertyChanged;
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (FilesTransmitted f in e.OldItems)
                f.PropertyChanged -= FilesTransmitted_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    void FilesTransmitted_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "DocumentNumber")
        {
            _filesTransmittedChange = true;
        }
        _refreshViews = true;
    }
```

and the ObservableCollection constructor:

```
class ObservableFilesTransmitted : ViewableCollection<FilesTransmitted>
{
    public ObservableFilesTransmitted(DocControlDC dataDc, int ID)
    {
        foreach (FilesTransmitted ftran in dataDc.FilesTransmitteds.Where(x=>x.JobID==ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.TransmittalName))
        {
            this.Add(ftran);
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger does not stop in the oFTrnCollectionChanged.  I think because the call to create the observable collection happens before I add the CollectionChanged event.  But obvously I can't switch those two lines.  I've looked at various StackOverflow and CodeProject topics on this, and it seems like what I have should work.  Do I need to add and remove a dummy item just to get the CollectionChanged hander called?  What am I missing?

It seems like perhaps I should have a constructor (for the observable collection) that does not add any members, and a function that adds the members from the database.  Then I can call new, add the collectionchanged handler, and then fill the collection.  I am hoping to avoid that level of rewrite though, but perhaps it's the only reasonable way.

Comment: Observable collection should fire the property changed event automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run in to this the easiest way to solve it is just subscribe manually at the start.

```
public FTViewModel(int JobID)
{
    _windowCloseAction = new DelegateCommand(OnWindowClose);
    _oFTrn = new ObservableFilesTransmitted(_dataDc, JobID);
    foreach(var item in _oFTrn)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += FilesTransmitted_PropertyChanged;
    }
    _oFTrn.CollectionChanged += oFTrnCollectionChanged;
}
```

However a even better solution is instead of using a class derived from `ObserveableCollection<T>` use a class derived from [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx). Any member raising their PropertyChanged event will cause the collection to raise [`ListChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742(v=vs.110).aspx) with the change type of `ItemChanged`

```
public FTViewModel(int JobID)
{
    _windowCloseAction = new DelegateCommand(OnWindowClose);
    _oFTrn = new ObservableFilesTransmitted(_dataDc, JobID);
    _oFTrn.CollectionChanged += oFTrnListChanged;
}

void oFTrnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
        if (e.PropertyDescriptor.Name == "DocumentNumber")
        {
            _filesTransmittedChange = true;
        }
    }
    _refreshViews = true;
}
```

Comment: facepalm.  Of course, I'm not sure why I did not immediately go this route, though I ended up there after my original fix (below).

Answer (score 0):

I have simply changed the ObservableCollection constructor and added a populate function:

New view model code:

```
    public FTViewModel(int JobID)
    {
        _oFTrn = new ObservableFilesTransmitted(_dataDc, JobID);
        _oFTrn.CollectionChanged += oFTrnCollectionChanged;
        _oFTrn.FillCollection();

    }
```

new ObservableCollection class:

```
class ObservableFilesTransmitted : ViewableCollection<FilesTransmitted>
{
    DocControlDC _dc = null;
    int _jobID = 0;

    public ObservableFilesTransmitted(DocControlDC dataDc, int ID)
    {
        _dc = dataDc;
        _jobID = ID;
    }

    public void FillCollection()
    {
        foreach (FilesTransmitted ftran in _dc.FilesTransmitteds.Where(x=>x.JobID==_jobID).OrderByDescending(x => x.TransmittalName))
        {
            this.Add(ftran);
        }
    }
}
```

And it all works as expected.  But it gets called for each item added.  I may play with the idea that I simply loop through the collection and add the propertychanged handler for each item in the viewmodel constructor.  Seems like less of a performance hit that way.